# Publishing a website in asp.net changes the spacing/size of the controls in the master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I published my asp.net website on IIS and the formatting of the master page controls are changed. Also I am not able to access the submenus on the master page after I put the page on IIS. How do I resolve it ?

Comment: I ask you the same question "How do we resolve it ?" with out any kind of informations ? Can you check if your css is not loading any more because the directory change ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you included all required CSS in the published folder ? Do you link you CSS files in a correct manner in the code or the links break when the directory structure changes under the published directory ? Post complete details for a robust answer.